# How to copy files from AWS S3 bucket to EC2 linux machine using AWS Lambda Functions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Need steps to create lambda functions for copying files from S3 bucket to a specific path in EC2 linux machine. Please help with code as well which need to give while creating lambda function.

Files will come daily to S3 bucket.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your actual situation? For example, _how_ are the files placed in the S3 bucket? _Why_ does the EC2 instance need to receive them? Are the files being created continuously? Please Edit your question to provide more information and we might then be able to offer an alternative option.

Comment: Yes John ! Files will come everyday in S3 bucket in an interval of may be 1-2 hours  and I want to automate this process everytime files come it should move to EC2 instance to a specific path. Please suggest

Comment: But _why_ do you specifically need the files in the Amazon EC2 instance? Will it be processing them? Why can't the software running on the EC2 instance simply access the files on S3 directly?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda functions cannot copy files to an Amazon EC2 instance.

It is better for the instance to 'download' the files from S3 rather than trying to have something 'push' the files to the instance.